# Arrange unique contents of hash according to there occurences

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Suppose I am firing a activerecord statement and the resulting array of hash contains the following

I am sorry for the vague question without providing proper information

to be precise after running Item.joins(:item_categories).where(:item_categories => {:category_id => i.id})

I get the following

```
[#<Item id: 1, name: "Bat", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 1, name: "Bat", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 1, name: "Bat", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 2, name: "Base", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 2, name: "Base", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 2, name: "Base", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 3, name: "Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 3, name: "Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 3, name: "Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 4, name: "Ball", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 4, name: "Ball", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 4, name: "Ball", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 5, name: "Catchers Mitt", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 5, name: "Catchers Mitt", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 5, name: "Catchers Mitt", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:43">, 
#<Item id: 6, name: "Batting Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 6, name: "Batting Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 6, name: "Batting Glove", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 7, name: "Batting Helmet", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 7, name: "Batting Helmet", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 7, name: "Batting Helmet", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 8, name: "Baseball Cap", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 8, name: "Baseball Cap", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 8, name: "Baseball Cap", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 9, name: "Gear Cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 9, name: "Gear Cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 10, name: "Non Gear Cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 10, name: "Non Gear Cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 11, name: "Mountain Bike", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 11, name: "Mountain Bike", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 12, name: "Uni-cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">, 
#<Item id: 12, name: "Uni-cycle", created_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44", updated_at: "2014-02-10 00:28:44">]
```

In this case I not only want the output to be unique but also the hashes should be arranged according to the occurrences of there Item id:

Is there any method available for this?, do I have to work on my activerecord query or do I have to write the method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to show an array of hashes and not hashes with duplicate keys, you can use `Array#uniq` with a block to specify the criteria for uniqueness:

```
array = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 }, 
  { a: 1, b: 3 },
  { a: 2, b: 1 },
  { a: 2, c: 4 }
]

array.uniq {|hash| hash[:a] } 
#=> [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 1 }]
```

Comment: I have edited the question and provided more information to understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Hashes can't have duplicate keys, so no this is not possible.  See the documentation at
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html

"A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of **unique** keys and their values."

Comment: I have edited the question and provided more information to understand the question

Answer (score 0):

If you executed this:

```
h = {'name' => 'hank', 'name' => 'hank','name' => 'steve',
     'name' => 'brad', 'name' => 'brad','name' => 'brad' }
```

Ruby would not complain.  It would set `h['name']` to 'hank', then it would do that again, then it would change `h['name']` to 'steve' and then set `h['name']` to 'brad' three times, so you would end up with

```
h = { 'name' => 'brad' }
```

If you changed the keys so they were unique, wanted each value to appear only once and didn't care which key/value pairs you removed to accomplish that, here's an easy way to do it:

```
h = {'name1' => 'hank', 'name2' => 'hank', 'name3' => 'steve',
     'name4' => 'brad', 'name5' => 'brad', 'name6' => 'brad' }

h.invert.invert #=> {"name2"=>"hank", "name3"=>"steve", "name6"=>"brad"}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and provided more information to understand the question